# Like Page Photo From Website PHP SDK 5.0

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

Was wondering if its possible to like a **page post photo** on Facebook from a website using the PHP SDK version 5?

I have managed to authenticate a user using the SDK but having troubles finding out if this is possible.

Any examples would be appreciated (if its possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. Not in the name of the app user.

Facebook has recently removed the possibility to like Facebook objects such as posts, photos and comments via API in the name of a user.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#nov-17th--2016

Comment: Cheers for the info CBroe! That blows - stupid Facebook :/